# display text in uiwebview in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I want to display data which is text data  ,  in the uiwebview can some one guide how to do the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use UIWebViews "loadHTMLString" method.

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString  *)string baseURL:(NSURL  *)baseURL
```

example:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"MyText" baseURL:nil];
```