# HTML string in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display text in uiwebview in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708221/display-text-in-uiwebview-in-iphone)

I have a String in HTML format.

I want to first convert This HTML string into normal string and then display the converted normal string into webview.(Also I want it in 3 paragraphs.)

How to do it in UIWebview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will help your problem for convert html in text
[How to convert NSString HTML markup to plain text NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606134/iphone-xcode-how-to-convert-nsstring-html-markup-to-plain-text-nsstring)

for other problem
try this link
[display text in uiwebview in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708221/display-text-in-uiwebview-in-iphone)

you can use

```
NSString *str = [self.mYwebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                                      @"document.body.textContent"];
```

Answer (score 3):

try this?

```
NSString *myText = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                                          @"document.body.textContent"];
```